# Scala Matrix(50x50) Mismatch Error with Spark RDD

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, matrix

When I try to write my matrix with below code I get the mismatch error defined beneath the code. I would like to be able to print this out to a csv file as it is hard to observe such large matrix on the console.
So my question is:
1- How can I fix this error?
2- How can I print "correlMatrix" to a csv file? (I tried multiple ways but errors occur)
Your help is much appreciated!

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.{MultivariateStatisticalSummary, Statistics}

object Correlation {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Correlation")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val file = "/data.csv"   
    val data = sc.textFile(file).map(line => Vectors.dense(line.split (",").map(_.toDouble).distinct))    
    val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(data, "pearson")
    println(correlMatrix.toString)

    sc.stop()
  }
}



 Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 4.5 KB, free 366.0 MB)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.5 KB, free 366.0 MB)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on 192.168.178.50:34281 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:419) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2))
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 4.0 with 3 tasks
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4895 bytes)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11, localhost, executor driver, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4895 bytes)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4895 bytes)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/tolga/Desktop/mics18-2/big-data/homework2/covtype.csv/covtype.csv:0+33554432
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/tolga/Desktop/mics18-2/big-data/homework2/covtype.csv/covtype.csv:67108864+8060453
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/tolga/Desktop/mics18-2/big-data/homework2/covtype.csv/covtype.csv:33554432+33554432
18/03/24 16:47:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 13 but got 12.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/24 16:47:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 13 but got 12.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/24 16:47:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 12 but got 13.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/24 16:47:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 12 but got 13.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/24 16:47:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/03/24 16:47:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 13 but got 12.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11) on localhost, executor driver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 13 but got 12.) [duplicate 1]
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 4
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 4 (treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:419) failed in 0.189 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 12 but got 13.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 failed: treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:419, took 0.256279 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 12 but got 13.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1008)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1128)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeColumnSummaryStatistics(RowMatrix.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeCovariance(RowMatrix.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.correlation.PearsonCorrelation$.computeCorrelationMatrix(PearsonCorrelation.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.correlation.Correlations$.corrMatrix(Correlation.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics$.corr(Statistics.scala:74)
    at Correlation$.main(Correlation.scala:43)
    at Correlation.main(Correlation.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 12 but got 13.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.add(MultivariateOnlineSummarizer.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix$$anonfun$17.apply(RowMatrix.scala:420)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$25.apply(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.178.50:4040
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/03/24 16:47:32 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3d7a6fd5-7783-4c93-97ff-92e57f90470f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below line in your exception. It is clearly showing dimensions mismatch exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when adding new sample. Expecting 13 but got 12.
```

Possible Solution: Remove distinct from map function or pass same number of values for each row.

Follow below link to save correlMatrix

[Save Spark org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649904/save-spark-org-apache-spark-mllib-linalg-matrix-to-a-file)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I am not supposed to not know the number of rows exactly I should not give a certain number. On the other hand, I have to use distinct as per request of the task. Can I do any other work around?